# Uploading files blocks my browser

Tags: php, ftp, copy

When I try to upload a file via php `copy` or ftp `put` the page is loading and I therefore can not access other pages of the site before the upload completes.
Other pages are loaded after the upload actually is done.
Opening pages in other browsers does work.

Is uploading a file blocking my browser and if yes, why and how do I work around it?

Comment: @Akhil.Please add code what you tried without looking code how someone can check where you doing wrong.Thanks.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "I can't open". What _exactly_ happens if you try?

Comment: im using simple ftp put upload. no errors in code, files uploading is fine.

Comment: but ftp upload takes more time for large files, so i tried to open upload ppage again to upload new one, but its not opening before the 1st upload cmplt

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to the locking of session files.

Try to use the session_write_close().

Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time. When using framesets together with sessions you will experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. You can reduce the time needed to load all the frames by ending the session as soon as all changes to session variables are done.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-write-close.php